# MQI Connections - Out of limit - WMQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have tool connecting to MQ to list queue , channels for admin use..
When i try to list all active channels it shows error "Out of MQI Connections for Queue Manager "QM2" , Increase MQI connection pool for Queue Manager "QM2".

i don't see any max channels reached errors in Queue Manager logs, also we have Max Channels set to 6k.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That error message has come from the tool. What does it say you should do as a result of it reporting that error? Does your tool have a setting for a connection pool? Can you say what the tool is?

Comment: Its a custom java tool...  let me check with developer if it has a connection pool settings.. But that doesn't reflect in Queue Manager logs?

Comment: More over this tool connects to more than 10 Queue Managers. Only when i connect to particular Queue Manager QM2 is getting this error. to list all channels..

Comment: "Connection pooling" is usually a term used to describe to collection and reuse of connection handles at the application end. What the developer who created that error message in you custom Java tool mean by it, only he can say. If he is using it in the usual sense then it wouldn't reflect in the queue manager logs. It would be interesting to know if the error was as a result of a particular MQ reason code though.

Comment: yes, it is setting in the code, by increasing the connection pool value by 4. we didn't see the error anymore. Thanks Morag!!

Comment: You might want to write an answer to your own question with what you did? Might someone in the future, especially if you say what the tool is.